# Shade a vertical strip Area in a MATLAB Plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to shade a vertical strip area in a MATLAB plot between to vertical lines.
I need to shade the part covered enclosed by the BLACK Curve, RED, BLUE & GREEN Lines.

[image]

I have tried the example from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167974/how-do-i-fill-in-the-area-between-two-lines-and-a-curve-thats-not-straight-in-m)

If the data for the plot is required, please let me know i will upload.

Comment: You have tried the example. What did you achieve when doing so? How does the output look? Please show what you have tried. And yes, sample data is appreciated, please check out [mcve].

Comment: Do you want to shade the part of the graph which is above or below the black curve?

Comment: Also, you have everything you need in the example you refer to in your post. As long as you don't show what you tried and where the exact problem is, this should be closed as a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fill in the area between two lines and a curve that's not straight in MATLAB (the region is not a polygon)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167974/how-do-i-fill-in-the-area-between-two-lines-and-a-curve-thats-not-straight-in-m)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
% some arbitrary data
x = -10:0.1:10;
y = abs(x).^0.5;
xleft = 0.5;
xright = 4;
fillStart = find(x>=0.5,1);
fillEnd = find(x>=4,1);
top = 2.5;
% plotting the lines
plot(x,y,'k',...
    x,ones(1,length(x))*top,'r',...
    ones(1,length(y)).*xleft,y,'g',...
    ones(1,length(y)).*xright,y,'b')
hold on
% filling the area
area(x(fillStart:fillEnd),y(fillStart:fillEnd),top, ...
    'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [0.5 0.5 0.5],'ShowBaseLine','off')
hold off
```

Which create this:

[image: fill area]

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you are after, (you need the equations for your respective lines) something like this should work

```
x = -5:0.1:5;
y = sqrt(abs(x));
figure
hold on
fill([2, 4, 4, 2], [0, 0, 2, 2], 'g')
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

From the `fill` documentation

> fill(X,Y,C) fills the 2-D polygon defined by vectors X and Y
>       with the color specified by C.  The vertices of the polygon
>       are specified by pairs of components of X and Y.  If necessary,
>       the polygon is closed by connecting the last vertex to the first.